# Rename file on uploading to Random name

Tags: php

I was wondering about the faster and the stronger way to rename a file to random ( Letters and Numbers )

Another issue is : I'm trying to put many NOT allowed type of files but actually my code is only work with one type !! So, if you may show me how I can put many types :)

This is my code:

```
   if ( $_REQUEST['do'] == "doUpload" )
{
  $TEMP = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
  $FileName = stripslashes($TEMP);  
  $FileType = strrchr($FileName ,'.'); 

  $box = $uploadDIR.'/'.$TEMP;

$notype= ".php";

if ($FileType == $notype){

echo "NOT ALLOWED TO ATTACH THIS KIND OF TYPES";

exit;
}
  if (file_exists($box))
  {
    echo "<center><b><font color=red>THE FILE ALREADY EXIST</font><br><br><a href='http://$httpname/$box' target='_blank'>THE LINK</a></b><center>";
  }
  else
  {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$box);

  echo " SUCCESS ";
```

Comment: echo md5($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']).".php";

Comment: why `RANDOM` name in particular? using a set series like 1,2,3,4 etc would ensure no duplication, after all random IS random not unique

Comment: `['tmp_name']` is already a random name to start with...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your disallowed file types I would do something like

```
$disallowedFileTypes = array('.php.', '.exe.', '.dmg');
if (in_array($FileType, $disallowedFiled)) {
    echo 'error';
    exit;
} else {
    // run upload
}
```

Oh and the way you are checking for the extension is flawed as it would break if a file was uploaded with a . in the name eg `my.file.php`

It would be better to use the phpinfo() method http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo($FileName);
$FileType = $path_parts['extension'];
?>
```

For random file names take a look at the PHP functions for exactly that

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php

Comment: file extension checking is not a good way to go. always use server-side mime-type checking, e.g `fileinfo`.

Comment: Very true.  I was trying to stay in context of OP's code, but to expand it yes MIME type checking is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You could use uniqid():

```
$FileName = uniqid();
```

Answer (score 0):

I work on an allow list rather than an exclusion list (there's more you don't want vs the ones you do want)

```
$allowedExtensions = array("txt","rtf","doc","pdf","docx","xlsx","xls","ppt","pptx","zip","rar","DOC","DOCX","mdb","MDB");

// check like this
if(!in_array($extension, $allowedExtensions)) {
    $adderr = "Invalid File Type. Please upload an allowed file type.";
}
```

For file naming I always go with a combination of the date with time stamp + the file name as if you just go with md5() of the file name as suggested above while  its rare its still possible to get duplicates over a large enough dataset. By implementing the time protocol you never get duplicates.

`$newname = md5(date("Y-m-d H:i:s").$_FILES['pricelist']['tmp_name'].$filename);`